# JavaFX animate between panes

Tags: java, javafx, transition

I'm building a card game in JavaFX and I have an `AnchorPane` as `root`.

Under the `AnchorPane` I have a `HBox` for displaying the cards ant the bottom of the screen and a `Pane` to display the pile of cards.

What I want to do is to animate the card when selected and it should move from the HBox to the Pane.

I'm trying to use `TranslateTransition` with `setFromX()`, `setFromY()`, `setToX()`, `setToY()`.

The problem is that when I'm setting the x and y it is in reference to the `HBox` and not in reference to the `root`.
So if I want to move the card up from the `HBox` I need to give it a negative `y` value.

Is there a way to create animation with reference to the `root` pane so I will only give it the `x` and `y` and it will move the card there?

Hope that it was clear...

Thanks.